# std::unordered_map insertion error

Tags: c++, insert, c++11, compiler-errors, unordered-map

I have the following unordered_map, that maps a pointer to an object of type Item with a key of type int.

```
typedef std::unordered_map<int, Item*> ItemList;
ItemList Items;
```

However, in my addItem method, I receive a strange error at compilation.

```
void ItemManager::addItem(Item *it)  {
    int i = it->getItemID();
    Items.insert(ItemList::value_type(i, *it));
}
```

Yields:

```
item_manager.cc: In member function ‘void ItemManager::addItem(Item*)’:
item_manager.cc:31:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<const int, Item*>::pair(int&, Item&)’
item_manager.cc:31:51: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:140:2: note: template<class ... _Args1, class ... _Args2> std::pair::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:135:2: note: template<class _U1, class _U2> std::pair::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:131:2: note: template<class _U1, class _U2, class> std::pair::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:125:2: note: template<class _U2, class> std::pair::pair(const _T1&, _U2&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:120:2: note: template<class _U1, class> std::pair::pair(_U1&&, const _T2&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:112:17: note: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int, _T2 = Process*, std::pair<_T1, _T2> = std::pair<const int, Process*>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:112:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:108:21: note: template<class _U1, class _U2> constexpr std::pair::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:103:26: note: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with _T1 = const int, _T2 = Process*]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:103:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘Process’ to ‘Process* const&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:99:26: note: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair() [with _T1 = const int, _T2 = Process*]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:99:26: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

Any ideas what could be causing these errors? I'm new to C++, so I have been working off of examples of unordered_maps I've found around the web. Any help is greatly appreciated. Please and thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values in your map are of type `Item*`, so you need to insert `Item*`, not `Item`. This line

```
 Items.insert(ItemList::value_type(i, *it));
```

should be

```
Items.insert(ItemList::value_type(i, it));
```

Comment: @RMartin : The best approach to pointers is to _not use them_ unless you absolutely have to. I can't imagine that you couldn't use `std::unordered_map<int, Item>` here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to dereference the pointer:

```
void ItemManager::addItem(Item *it)  {
    int i = it->getItemID();
    Items.insert(ItemList::value_type(i, it));
}
```